# GraphQL mutation: Invariant Violation: Must contain a query definition

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to make a **`mutation`** call to my graphQL server from a react application. The react code looks like the following:

```
client.query({
  query: gql`
    mutation{
        addTeam(input:{name:"Somename", label:"somelabel"})
        {error, status}
    }`
 }).then((resp: any) => {
      console.log("Success", resp);
 }).catch(err => {
      throw err;
 })
```

And I am getting the following error:

[image]

But if I change the same request, from `mutation` to `query`, and make the necessary changes in my node-graphQL-server to handle it as `query` instead of `mutation` the same code works.

### Apollo-Client `Mutation` [docs says](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/mutations.html)

> In GraphQL, mutations are identical to queries in syntax, the only difference being that you use the keyword `mutation` instead of `query`...

Oh and BTW, the same `mutation` query WORKS in **`Playground`**.
Please help guys, my work is kinda stopped coz of this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You should use the `mutate` method of the client for mutations, not the `query` method. The options for the method can be found [in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html#ApolloClient.mutate). Apollo is opinionated about how queries and mutations are treated, so each method has different options that are appropriate to each operation's behavior (for example, `mutate` includes a `refetchQueries` option).

```
client.mutate({
  mutation: gql`
    mutation {
      addTeam(input:{name:"Somename", label:"somelabel"}) {
        error
        status
      }
    }`,
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize that I was user "client.query" for mutation. +1

Comment: Jeez! "client.mutate"... who knew?

Comment: This answer solved my problem, but can this be done with a single `gql` string as opposed to the `mutation` object (where `mutation` is used twice)?  I'm using the `@rest` call from the [Apollo Client docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest/).  They use a `gql` query string, followed by a `client.query({ query })` api call.  Curious if that's possible with the same inputs that you used here.

Comment: your doc link no longer works, could you update it please?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a GitHub issue that speaks of this error: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1539

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when one names their query constant different from **query** or **mutation**

e.g.

```
const query1 = gql`
  query GetPost {
    id
    title
  }
`
const result = await apolloClient.query(query: query1)
```